# How can I minimize floating point error when multiplying normal distribution PDFs?

Tags: probability-theory, numerical-algorithms

If you multiply two normal distribution PDFs with means $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ and variances $v_1$ and $v_2$, then [according to this page](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/sasp/Product_Two_Gaussian_PDFs.html), the new mean is

$$\mu = \frac{\mu_1 v_2 + \mu_2 v_1}{v_1 + v_2}$$

and the new variance is

$$v = \frac{v_1 v_2}{v_1 + v_2}.$$

However, if I use those expressions directly to combine several distributions sequentially, the floating point errors quickly pile up. Is there an algorithm for doing this stably?

Comment: Can you give a concrete example when "the floating point errors quick pile up"?

Answer (score 1):

While there is [an entire subject](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_stability) that studies how to prevent or reduce floating point errors from piling up, it happens we have a shortcut here.

Let $\mathcal N(u, \sigma)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2} } e^{ -\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2} }$ , the normal distribution with mean $u$ and standard derivation $\sigma$.
Suppose we are given $n$ Gaussian normal distribution $\mathcal N_i(u_i, \sigma_i)$ . What is the product of $n$ of them? It turns out,

$$\prod_{i=1}^n \mathcal N(\mu_i,\sigma_i)= s\mathcal N (\mu,\sigma)$$ 
where
$$
\frac1{\sigma^{2}} = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac1{\sigma_i^{2}}\,, \quad
\frac\mu{\sigma^2} = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\mu_i}{\sigma_i^{2}}
$$
and
$$
s =  (2\pi)^{\frac{1-n}2} \frac{\sigma}{\prod_{i=1}^n \sigma_i}\exp\left(\frac12 \left(\frac{\mu^2}{\sigma^2} - \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\mu_i^2}{\sigma_i^2}\right) \right)
$$

If you use the above formula to compute, floating point errors should not be a concern any more.

Please note [the reference you used](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/sasp/Product_Two_Gaussian_PDFs.html) is misleading in the sense the product function is not a probability distribution function.

---

Exercise. Prove the above formula for the product of $n$ normal distribution.